# XML parsing failed because the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following code where I'm passing an XML string.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

DECLARE @xml XML =N'<Locations><LocId>USA</LocId><LocId>AUS</LocId><LocId>GER</LocId></Locations>'

CREATE TABLE #tmpLoc (LocId Varchar(100)) 

INSERT INTO #tmpLoc
    SELECT t.c.value('.','varchar(100)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Locations/LocId') t(c)

SELECT * FROM #tmpLoc
```

I get the following error when I run this query:

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

I went through the documentation for XML data types and found that XQuery needs the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` to be ON. I set it to ON and it worked. The documentation does not give any explanation about the reason behind this. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain why the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` needs to be set to ON for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: It's just the way that Microsoft designed it. All new features are designed so that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is on, because having it `OFF` is partly deprecated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304018/sql-server-xml-data-type-and-quoted-identifier